# Cannot create executable

Tags: makefile, omnet++

I had a project running pretty neat until I had to add a few features. The features was a few lines of code and a new .msg definition file. After the additions when build the program shows this message:

```
make MODE=debug CONFIGNAME=gcc-debug all 
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `mkdir -p "out/gcc-debug/" && echo "-g -Wall   -I/usr/include -fno-stack-protector  -DHAVE_PCAP -DXMLPARSER=libxml -DWITH_PARSIM -DWITH_NETBUILDER  -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.6/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.6/include/cppconn" -IC:/local/boost_1_58_0/ -I. -IC:/Users/LuisH.Forchesatto/Downloads/omnetpp-4.6/include" >out/gcc-debug//.last-copts'
Creating executable: out/gcc-debug//DB5.exe
```

The files of the project are below. I don't have the files before the modifications so is not possible to undo the changes. Once I posted here a similar issue and a few modifications to the makefile file solved gracefully, but this time it seems alright for me.

Dropbox link with the project files:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85576999/Db5.rar

Comment: Can you post more of the error message? There might be an indication of what failed in it.

Comment: Of course!

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85576999/Db5/output.txt

Had to put on dropbox because it was too many lines.

Comment: Did you recently install mySQL? The error message refers to ( characters and there seems to be one in that path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by having more than one .cc file which holds the nodes algorithm.

Putting all C++ code within the same file and including other routines via header (.h) files seems not to generate any errors.

Comment: Great that it fixed, but be aware that the original error was dumped by the makefile not the compiler so it definitely should not have to do anything with how you organize your code inside the .cc files. Could be that during the reorg you accidentally fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

- Remove anything that is MYSQL related. You seem to be messed up the INCLUDE path.
- Once your project compiles again, you may add mysql stuff again (if you need it BUT:
- never use spaces in paths! Use the short filename form if you have to add something that is under a path with spaces.
- never use \ use forward slashes. (\ is an escape character in the bash shell used by omnet)
- finally: use version control software even if you do local development. (git is great for this).