# Boost library files not recognized although included in PATH

Tags: c++, mysql, boost, omnet++

Boost library header files were included in PATH AND SYMBOLS but building the program generates an error message:

```
10:27:13 **** Incremental Build of configuration gcc-debug for project DB8 ****
make MODE=debug CONFIGNAME=gcc-debug all 
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `mkdir -p "out/gcc-debug/" && echo "-g -Wall   -    I/usr/include -fno-stack-protector -DXMLPARSER=libxml -DWITH_PARSIM -    DWITH_NETBUILDER  -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/cppconn" -IC:/local/boost_1_59_0/boost -I. -    IC:/Users/LuisH.Forchesatto/Downloads/omnetpp-4.6/include" >out/gcc-debug//.last-    copts'
defaultSensor.cc
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/cppconn/connection.h:33:0,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/mysql_connection.h:30,
                 from dbWriteWin.h:6,
                 from defaultSensor.cc:6:
C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/cppconn/warning.h:40:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-    Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
 ^
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/cppconn/variant.h:38:0,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/cppconn/connection.h:35,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/mysql_connection.h:30,
                 from dbWriteWin.h:6,
                 from defaultSensor.cc:6:
C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/cppconn/exception.h:48:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-    Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
 ^
C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/cppconn/exception.h:52:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-    Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning(push)
 ^
C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/cppconn/exception.h:53:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-    Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning(disable: 4275)
 ^
C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/cppconn/exception.h:58:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-    Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning(pop)
 ^
In file included from dbWriteWin.h:6:0,
                 from defaultSensor.cc:6:
C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++     1.1.6/include/mysql_connection.h:31:32: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such     file or directory
 #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
                                ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//defaultSensor.o] Error 1
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'out/gcc-debug//defaultSensor.o' failed

10:27:14 Build Finished (took 1s.183ms)
```

The library is installed in the system, the folder/file exists in the computer and it's path is correct. What can be causing this error?

Contents of path and symbols:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85576999/paths%20and%20symbols.png

Contents of the boost library folder:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85576999/boost%20folder.png

Comment: The linker doesn't use `PATH` to look for libraries, `PATH` is used by the shell to find executable commands. If the libraries are installed in a non-standard location you have to add the path to the list that the linker searches with the `-L` option.

Comment: That's already on the link options:


# Additional libraries (-L, -l options)
LIBS =  -lC:/local/boost_1_59_0

Comment: Maybe you want e.g. `-IC:/local/boost_1_59_0/include` or something similar?

Comment: And without knowing the exact directory layout of your installation, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: There is no "include" folder on boost_1_59_0. I tried to add with -I parameter the path but didn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use spaces in paths. I suggest moving (or reinstalling) MySQL Connector libraries to the folder with simple name **without spaces**, for example: `c:\mysqlconnector`.
2. Check whether the path to `boost` is set for C++ language too - on the `Path and Symbols` screen there is `Assembly` language focused.
3. Take into account [these cluses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662266/cannot-create-executable/32691148#32691148) provided by Rudi.

Comment: The solution proposed solved the problem! =) At first, I though of just renaming the paths to the libraries, but that didn't changed the outcome. Then I reinstalled the libraries with paths without spaces and special caracteres and now everything is recognized and included. Thank you very much for your help.